# What are reds and trans in Image processing

Tags: image-processing

I'm trying to understand this code, however I'm unable to deduce the meaning of reds and trans. I would be glad if you can help with it:

```
import sys
import Image

# pixel constants in hex
trans="\x00\x00\x00\x00"
# reds most to least, the last is trans and used as a noise factor
reds=("\xf1\x34\x00\xff" , "\xfa\x00\x2f\xff",
   "\xf1\x36\x36\xff", "\xfe\x74\x74\xff", "\xfe\xc3\xc3\xff",
   "\xf9\xcb\xcb\xff", "\xf1\xd3\xd3\xff", "\x00\x00\x00\x00")
```

The complete code is at: https://matsu-project.googlecode.com/svn-history/r28/trunk/streaming-image-processing/src/reduce.py

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The numbers appear to be [RGBA](http://www.css3.info/preview/rgba/) values: red, green, blue, and alpha (transparency).

`reds` appear to be mostly red-tinted colors (except the last entry, which is a completely transparent  item).

`trans` is the transparent "color".